# Why isn't my while loop functioning properly?

Tags: c, loops, while-loop

My task is to exit the loop only if the user types "n" or "N".

Here is my code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    char alpha;

    printf("This loop will repeat. Do you wnat to repeat? (Press n or N to exit). ");
    scanf("%c", &alpha);
    
    if(alpha != 'n' || alpha != 'N')
    {
        printf("Do you still want to repeat? (Press n or N to exit). ");
    }
    
    while(alpha != 'n' || alpha != 'N');
    return 0;
}
```

The problem is my code is not looping at all.

Comment: Consider this.  `alpha` will ALWAYS be either not equal to 'n' or not equal to 'N'.  You need `&&` there, not `||`.  You should have `while` where you have `if`, and you should delete the second `while`.

Answer (score 1):

Comments in code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    char alpha;

    printf("This loop will repeat. Do you wnat to repeat? (Press n or N to exit). ");
    // You need a "do" to start a block of code,
    // otherwise the "while" loop runs forever
    do
    {
        // Put a space before the format specifier to consume the trailing
        // newline left by previous calls to scanf
        scanf(" %c", &alpha);
        // You want the "and" operator, not "or"
        if(alpha != 'n' && alpha != 'N')
        {
            printf("Do you still want to repeat? (Press n or N to exit). ");
        }
    }
    // Same here, you want the "and" operator, not "or"
    while(alpha != 'n' && alpha != 'N');
    return 0;
}
```

A better approach (test the condition only once and check the result of `scanf`):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    char alpha;

    printf("This loop will repeat. Do you wnat to repeat? (Press n or N to exit). ");
    while (scanf(" %c", &alpha) == 1)
    {
        if(alpha != 'n' && alpha != 'N')
        {
            printf("Do you still want to repeat? (Press n or N to exit). ");
        }
        else break;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This reminds me of [de Morgan's Laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan's_laws)